# kubectl doesnt show username/password of secret?

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, minikube

So, I set up a few secrets in my cluster, but when I want to see them, I get no data response:

```
a@b:~/ kubectl create secret generic test-sc --username=test --password='tested' 
secret/test-sc created

a@b:~/ kubectl describe secrets/test-sc
Name:         test-sc
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your secret is not correct.

You are specifying text so you should use `--from-literal`.

In your example

`kubectl create secret generic test-sc --from-literal=username=test --from-literal=password='tested'`

This is explained in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).